# Flask-login not redirecting to previous page

Tags: python, redirect, authentication, flask, flask-login

I have seen quite a few questions with this in mind, but haven't been able to address my issue. I have a Flask app with flask-login for session management. And, when I try to view a page without logging in, I get redirected to a link in form of `/login/?next=%2Fsettings%2F`

The issue is, as far as I could have it understand, that the "next" argument holds the part of the site I actually need, but when submitting a request to a login form, it is done via `POST`, so this argument is no longer available for me to redirect it to.

I tried using `Request.path` from [Request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path%20Request) (and url) but both just return the `/login/` as the request url/path, not the actual `/login/?next=xxx`.

My login method is as follows:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #getting the user
        user = User.get(request.form['username'])
        if user.user is None:
            return redirect('/login/')
        #actual login proces
        if user and check_password_hash(user.user.password, request.form['password']):
            login_user(user, remember=remember)
            #the redirection portion of the login process
            return redirect(request.path or ("/")) # I tried various options there but without success, like request.args['next'] and such

        return redirect('/login/')

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`request.path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=request.path#flask.Request.path) is not what you're looking for. It returns the actual path of the URL. So, if your URL is `/a/?b=c`, then `request.path` returns `/a`, not `c` as you are expecting.

The `next` parameter is after the `?` in the URL, thus it is part of the "query string". Flask has already parsed out items in the query string for you, and you can retrieve these values by using [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args). If you sent a request to the URL `/a/?b=c` and did `request.args.get('b')`, you would receive `"c"`.

So, you want to use `request.args.get('next')`. The documentation [shows how this works in an example](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works).

Another thing to keep in mind is that when you are creating your login form in HTML, you don't want to set the "action" attribute. So, don't do this..

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    ...
</form>
```

This will cause the POST request to be made to `/login`, not `/login/?next=%2Fsettings%2F`, meaning your `next` parameter will not be part of the query string, and thus you won't be able to retrieve it. You want to leave off the "action" attribute:

```
<form method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

This will cause the form to be posted to the current URL (which should be `/login/?next=%2Fsettings%2f`).

Comment: As I said, I tried with Request.url and similar, path was there just an example. Neverthe less, the issue was with the action in the form element, I removed that, used the argument as the docs suggested and voila, its working now. This is great and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I didn't even think to check the form tag where `action="/"`. DUH! :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoengine sessions to pass 'next_url' parameter with flask session (`from flask import session`). In py file where you define your app and login_manager:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngineSessionInterface
app.session_interface = MongoEngineSessionInterface(db)

@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized_callback():
    session['next_url'] = request.path
    return redirect('/login/')
```

and then in login view:

```
def login():
    # ... if success
    next_url = session.get('next_url', '/')
    session.clear()
    return redirect(next_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have resolved this with the accepted answer. I had a bug in my code, but this is solvable without the `mongoengine` so I went that way.

Comment: I see, just for those who will have in future such problem and who use  mongo, I decided to share with my solution