# Flask request.args.get('next') value disappears after logging in

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I'm following Miguel sir's book on flask.
I'm stuck in the login function where I send the email confirmation to the user and then after clicking the link it will ask the user to login but after logging in the request.args.get('next') variable is empty hence the confirm function is never executed. I suspect this is caused due to the before_app_request.  I'm very new to flask and I've spent two days trying to fix this. Miguels version works fine, mine seem's to be cursed. Someone else's view is really needed. Thanks for reading.

> view.py

```
@auth.before_app_request
def before_request():
    print("\tREQUEST ENDPOINT ::"+str(request.endpoint))
    print("\tREQUEST ARGS ::"+str(request.args.get('next')))
    if current_user.is_authenticated \
            and not current_user.confirmed \
            and request.endpoint \
            and request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.' \
            and request.endpoint != 'static':
        return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))



@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form=RegForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user=User(fname=form.fname.data,
        lname=form.lname.data,
        email=form.email.data,
        organization_name=form.username.data,
        password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        #db.session.commit()
        token=user.generate_confirmation_token()

        send_email(user.email,'Confirm your Account','email/auth/confirm',user=user,token=token)
        flash('A confirmation Email has been sent, Please check your inbox','success')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        #except Exception as e:
        #    print("LINE 48 EMAIL: "+str(e))
        #    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('Landing/entry.html',form=form)



@auth.route('/confirm/<token>')
@login_required
def confirm(token):
    if current_user.confirmed:
        return redirect(url_for('viewhome.home'))
    if current_user.confirm(token):
        print('\tENTERED')
        flash('Account confirmed ','success')
    else:
        flash('Invalid Link or Link has expired','Warning')
    return redirect(url_for('viewhome.home'))

@auth.route('/confirm')
@login_required
def resend_confirmation():
    token=current_user.generate_confirmation_token()
    send_email(current_user.email,'Confirm your account','email/auth/confirm',user=current_user,token=token)
    flash("A new confirmation email has been sent","success")
    return redirect(url_for('viewhome.home'))



@auth.route('/unconfirmed')
def unconfirmed():
    if current_user.is_anonymous or current_user.confirmed:
        return redirect(url_for('viewhome.home'))
    return render_template('Landing/unconfirmed.html')

@auth.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user=User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user,form.remember_me.data)
            print("REQUEST ARGS "+str(request.args.get('next')))
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('viewhome.home'))
        flash('Invalid username or password')
    return render_template('Landing/login.html',form=form)
    #if form.validate_on_submit():
        #user=User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        #if user is not None and User.verify_password(form.password.data)
@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash("You have been logged out","success")
    return redirect(url_for("viewhome.home"))
```

> users.py

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    fname=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=False)
    lname=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=False)
    organization_name=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True,index=True)
    password_hash=db.Column(db.String(128),nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(30),unique=True,nullable=False,index=True)
    confirmed=db.Column(db.Boolean,default=False)
    rel=db.relationship('Domains',backref='users',lazy=True)


    #def __init__(self,fname,lname,password,email,organization_name):
    #    self.fname=fname
    #    self.lname=lname

    #    self.password=password
    #    self.email=email
    #    self.organization_name=organization_name

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError("password is readonly")

    @password.setter
    def password(self,password):
       self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password,method='pbkdf2:sha512',salt_length=64)


    def verify_password(self,password):
       return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def generate_confirmation_token(self,expiration=3600):
        s=Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],expiration)
        return s.dumps({'confirm':self.id})

    def confirm(self,token):
        print("\tCONFIRM TOKEN FUNCTION")
        s=Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data=s.loads(token)
        except:
            print("\tERROR HERE IN LINE 48")
            return False
        if data.get('confirm') != self.id:
            print("DEBUG:: " + int( self.id))
            return False
        print('\t\tLINE 54 REACHED')
        self.confirmed=True
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
        return True



    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Users %r >" % self.organization_name

class Domains(db.Model):
    __tablename__='domains'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
    domains=db.Column(db.String(25),unique=True,nullable=False)

    def __init__(self,user_id,domain):
        self.user_id=user_id
        self.domains=domain

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Domains %r >" % self.domains


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print("FROM USERs :: "+user_id )
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

> Landing/Login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from "_macro.html" import render_field %}

    {% block title %}Login- Progressus Bootstrap template{% endblock title%}
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/cust.css') }}" media="screen">



{{super()}}
{% endblock css %}



{% block page_content %}

<!--<header  id="head" class="secondary"></header>-->

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">

        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Registration</li>
        </ol>

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Article main content -->
            <article class="col-xs-12 maincontent">
            <header class="page-header">

                </header>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body tabs">

                            <ul class="tab-links clearfix">
                                <li class="active"><h3 class="thin">Login</h3></a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <!--<p class="text-center text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="signin.html">Login</a> adipisicing elit. Quo nulla quibusdam cum doloremque incidunt nemo sunt a tenetur omnis odio. </p>
                            -->
                            <hr>

                            <div class="tab-content">

                        <div id="register-form" class="tab">
                            <form action="{{url_for('auth.login')}}" method="post" name="register">
                                {{form.csrf_token}}
                                <div class="top-margin">
                                    <label> Email</label>
                                       {{ render_field(form.email,class="form-control") }}
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="top-margin">
                                       <label>Password</label>
                                       {{ render_field(form.password,class="form-control") }}
                           </div>


                           <hr>

                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <label class="checkbox">

                                       {{ form.remember_me }}
                                       Keep me logged in
                                   </label>
                               </div>
                               <div  class="col-lg-4 text-right">

                                   <!--<button class="btn btn-action" type="submit" >Register</button>-->

                                       {{ form.submit_log(class="btn btn-action") }}

                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </form>
                   </div>

                    </div>

                    </div><!-- panel body-->

                </div><!-- panel -->

            </article>
            <!-- /Article -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- /container -->


{% endblock page_content %}
{% block script %}
{{super()}}


{% endblock script%}
```

Comment: *Don't link to pictures of code*. Post it *here*, as text.

Comment: okay really sorry.

Comment: Can you also add your `Landing/login.html`? Per http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object, `request.args` contains only the URL params of the page. Perhaps you're not setting those in the form in `login.html` properly?

Comment: The flow of email confirmation is: Register->Email confirmation-> click on the link-> and then it displays the login page because of flask-login login_required decorator and after logging in the link is verified the problem arises here after the login the next parameter is none But Miguel sir's code works and it's exactly the same

Comment: Okay so I fixed the error thanks

Answer (score 5):

The one thing I hadn't followed is that we need not set the action variable in the form and since the book used the wtf quick form option I never noticed it

```
<form action="" method="Post">
```

[Flask-login not redirecting to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766291/flask-login-not-redirecting-to-previous-page)

I wasted two days behind this. I hope this helps anyone who stumbles over this.